# AngularJs - Submit button multiple repetition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, button, submit

i'm working on ACTIVI in AngularJS.

I need to submit forms, so i created it with a submit button. The problem is that each submit button is a bit different (one is for text type form, another for enum type forms) and with new form the previously button is repeated twice. 
As you can see this one is ok:

[image].

**But the next form repeat the previously submit button:**

[image]

This is the code in html

```
<div ng-controller="githubController3">
                <div ng-controller="githubControllerForm1">
                    <div ng-controller="completeTaskAction">
                        <form ng-submit="submitForm()">
                            <div ng-repeat="x in names">
                                {{ x.name }}*


                                <div ng-if="x.id=='name'">
                                    <input type="text" name="nome" ng-model="formData.properties[0].value" placeholder="{{x.name}}"> {{ value }} </input>
                                </div>

                                <div ng-if="x.id=='email'">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="formData.properties[1].value" placeholder="{{x.name}}"> {{ email }} </input>
                                </div>

                                <div ng-if="x.id=='income'">
                                    <input type="number" name="numero" ng-model="formData.properties[2].value" placeholder="{{x.name}}"> {{ income }} </input>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <div ng-controller="completeTaskAction">
                        <form ng-submit="submitForm()">
                            <br>
                            <button ng-show="x.type==enum" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span>Submit!
                            </button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div ng-controller="githubControllerForm1">
                <div ng-controller="completeTaskAction2">
                    <div ng-repeat="x in names">

                        <div ng-if="x.type=='enum'">
                            <!--/////////////////////////////////-->


                            <form ng-submit="submitForm2()">

                                <select ng-model="formData2.properties[0].value" ng-options="y.id as y.name for y in x.enumValues "></select>




                                <br>

                                <button ng-hide="x.type==enum" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit!
                                </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
```

I tried (as you can see) with ng-show / hide / ng-if but doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

The first form is working fine because the button is outside ng-repeat. In the second case the submit button is inside ng-repeat.